# How to pass SwipeEvent to view parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have LinearLayout and 3 TextViews in it. I petted swipeListner to linearLayout, but it's Childs overshadow swipes. I tried some things as onInterceptTouchEvent(), setted texts non-clickable, non-focusable, but it didn't help.

How can I listen swipes over this texts on the whole linear layout?

Thanks everyone for the answers in advance !

Comment: show your code, its will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout><Your Views></LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
 </SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem cause I wasn't able to extend any ViewGroup, but than I figured it out and just added this:

`override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return true
    }`